# Google BigQuery: How to add partition manually

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a daily partitioned table with a single partition holding 10M rows.I want to add another 10M rows from 10 csv files (holding 1M rows each) for  yesterday's data into another partition. Do i have to create yesterday's partition manually and then load data into it ? how do i do it ?Is there any way i can directly load previous date records in a pre-existing table using 'BQ load' Command ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "daily partitioned table with a single partition holding 10M rows"? Do you mean you have roughly 10M rows per partition/day?

Comment: yes Chris...I have so far created one partition with today's date (20170517) and loaded 10M records init form GCS. I have to repeat this for yesterday's csv files. I hope, i have to create 20170516 partition first and then i can load in it from GCS.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special, just specify `tablename$partitiontime` as destination for the load command, i.e.

```
bq --time_partitioning_type=DAY --source_format=CSV
  'dataset.tbl$20170516' /tmp/file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Mosha Pasumansky...This solved my problem. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @BhavikDesai - then you should upvote and accept his answer.